# Validation in Child Model in Nested Attribute - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This are my files:

word.rb

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :word_answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :word_answers, allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: lambda {|attribute| attribute[:word_id].blank?}
end
```

word_answer.rb

```
class WordAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word
  validates :content, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

Is there any method that I can valiidate `validates :content, uniqueness: true, presence: true` of word_answer.rb in word.rb?

Rails 4.

I tried `validates_associated :word_answers` but it doesn't work.

I want to achieve is

(1) If I submit Word, it will give an error if there is no WordAnswer.

(2) If I submit Word, it will give an error if there is a BLANK WordAnswer.

(3) If a validation is WordAnswer is wrong, It will give an error if I submit Word.

Comment: Why do you need to validate in your `word` model since you performed those validations in `word_answer` model?

Comment: Because they are nested_attributes. It will save word without any word_answers

Comment: Why do you want `content` to be unique? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is like a question. Word = question, WordAnswer = choices.

Comment: I mean here, your `content` should be unique? Why did you name your column as content since you want it to be  unique? Imagine?

Comment: Ok what if content can not be unique, but I want it not to be blank, what would I do?

Comment: Sir, did you use `nested_form` gem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if we can add `validates :content, uniqueness: true, presence: true` to Word method but you can achieve validation for WordAnswer model in Word Model by adding a before_save & before_update filters.

I guess the validations in WordAnswer model will work fine as you want them to when you use nested attributes in the form and it will validate fine.

In other case kindly explain what you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to achieve is

(1) If I submit Word, and it has no WordAnswer, it will give an elegant error.

(2) If I submit Word, and its WordAnswer is blank, it will give an error

(3) If I add a condition to the WordAnswer, it will reflect if I submit Word.

Comment: @AldrinGravides For presence we can add front end validation so that answer content will not be blank & for validation check i am updating answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
validate :detail

def detail
    word_answers.each do |word_answer|
        if word_answer.content.blank?
            errors.add(:"word_answer.content", "must not be blank")
            word_answer.errors.add(:content, "must not be blank")
        end
    end
end
```

It should work if your models are associated correctly.

Comment: Also, if you use `nested_form`